# How to change datagrid header to follow other cell value in C# ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I would like to change a datagrid header to follow another cell value, in this case, the header must show the currency (example in image below).

The red bold text is the one that I want to display on header.

Please help.

[Header show content of other cell's value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gh7PI.jpg)

HTML:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlWarrant" runat="server" Width="100%" OnItemDataBound="dlWarrant_OnItemDataBound">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Table runat="server" ID="resulttable" Width="100%" >
      <asp:TableRow>
          <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="6" HorizontalAlign="Center">
             <asp:Label ID="lblTrusteeName" runat="server" CssClass="lblBoldText" Text='<%# Eval("TRUSTEE_NAME") %>' />
          </asp:TableCell>
      </asp:TableRow>
      <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="6" HorizontalAlign="left" > 
               <asp:DataGrid CellSpacing="1" runat="server" ID="dgWarrant2" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333"
                    GridLines="Both" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100%"
                    DataSource='<%# Eval("DETAILS2") %>' Font-Size="8.5pt" OnItemDataBound="dgWarrant2_OnItemDataBound">
                    <EditItemStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                    <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Mode="NumericPages" CssClass="PagerStyle" BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="TAXABLE_INCOME" HeaderText="TAXABLE INCOME ()" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center"
                                            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" DataFormatString="{0:#,##0.00}" ItemStyle-Width="20%" />
                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="MSIAN_TAX" HeaderText="TAX" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center"
                                            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" DataFormatString="{0:#,##0.00}" ItemStyle-Width="20%" />
                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="NON_TAXABLE_INCOME" HeaderText="NET NON-TAXABLE INCOME" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center"
                                            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" DataFormatString="{0:#,##0.00}" ItemStyle-Width="20%" />
                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="NET_PAYABLE" HeaderText="AMOUNT FOR REINVESTMENT" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center"
                                            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" DataFormatString="{0:#,##0.00}" ItemStyle-Width="20%" />
                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="REINV_UNITS" HeaderText="REINVESTMENT UNITS" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center"
                                            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" DataFormatString="{0:#,##0.00}" ItemStyle-Width="20%" />
                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="INCOME_TREATMENT" HeaderText="INCOME_TREATMENT" 
                                             ItemStyle-CssClass="hideGridColumn" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hideGridColumn" />
                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="CURRENCY" HeaderText="CURRENCY" />
                    </Columns>
               </asp:DataGrid>                                       
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
     </asp:Table>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Code behind c#:

```
protected void dgWarrant2_OnItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
        {
            //get grid as Item's parent
            DataGrid grid = e.Item.Parent.NamingContainer as DataGrid;

            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                if (e.Item.Cells[5].Text != "R")
                {
                    grid.Columns[4].HeaderStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
                    grid.Columns[4].ItemStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
                }
                else
                {
                    grid.Columns[4].HeaderStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    grid.Columns[4].ItemStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                }
            }
            else if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header)
            {
                e.Item.Cells[0].Text = "TAX (test)";

                // TODO: How to change header's currency to follow fund currency?

            }
        }
```

Comment: will there always one row? or it will take the first row of the data?

Comment: where do you put the data? in data table or list? please share the code where you loading data in DataGridView

Comment: Thanks for replying. There will always be 1 row. Load from datalist. I have no idea how to get the value from other cell.

Comment: I did a workaround for this, I've changed all the details that I want to display in the datagrid to just tables and labels, because it will always load 1 row anyway. 

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a workaround for this, I've changed all the details that I want to display in the datagrid to just tables and labels, because it will always load 1 row anyway.

Thanks all.